# How to make grep [A-Z] independent of locale?

Tags: grep, locale

I was doing some everyday grepping and suddenly discovered that something seemingly trivial does not work:

```
$ echo T | grep [A-Z]
```

No match.

How come T is not within A-Z range?

I changed the regex a tiny bit:

```
$ echo T | grep [A-Y]
```

A match!

Whoa! How is T within A-Y but not within A-Z?

Apparently this is because my environment is set to Estonian locale where Y is at the end of the alphabet but Z is somewhere in the middle: ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSŠZŽTUVWÕÄÖÜXY

```
$ echo $LANG
et_EE.UTF-8
```

This all came as a bit of a shock to me. 99% of the time I grep computer code, not Estonian literature. Have I been using grep the wrong way all the time? What all kind of mistakes have I made because of this in the past?

After trying several things I arrived at the following solution:

```
$ echo T | LANG=C grep [A-Z]
```

**Is this the recommended way to make grep locale-independent?**

Further more... would it be safe to define an alias like that:

```
$ alias grep="LANG=C grep"
```

**PS.** I'm also wondering of why are the character ranges like `[A-Z]` locale dependent in the first place while `\w` seems to be unaffected by locale (although the manual says `\w` is equivalent of `[[:alnum:]]` - but I found out the latter depends on locale while `\w` does not).

Comment: Please try all that again, but quote your expression `grep '[A-Z]'`, just to make sure the shell isn't expanding that.

Comment: Works exactly the same for me with and without quotes.

Comment: Works the same only because you don't have a file named A through Z. The shell tried to expand [A-Z], didn't find anything, and left it alone.  Use quotes to always pass patterns to grep.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't actually know that Bash supports expanding that kind of things. But I've been actually always quoting the grep arguments anyway - I just thought I'll leave them off to keep code samples shorter. Now smarter again.

Comment: The question "Is this the recommended way to make grep locale-independent?" isn't well-posed. `grep` has to use *some* locale; it can't operate without any locale at all.  I think you might want to rephrase to ask "Is this how to make grep use the old ASCII locale I'm used to?", which does have an answer: Yes.  `LC_ALL=C` will give you that old ASCII character set and collating order.  `LC_COLLATE=C` will allow the full local locale character set but make sure it sorts in the familiar ASCII way.  Is that what you want?

Comment: This is documented in [Character Classes and Bracket Expressions](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep).

Comment: tl;dr `LANG=C grep...` or `grep -P ...` are independent of locale.

Answer (score 4):

POSIX regular expressions, which Linux and FreeBSD grep support naturally, and some others support on request, have a series of [:xxx:] patterns that honor locales. See the man page for details.

```
   grep '[[:upper:]]'
```

As the []s are part of the pattern name you need the outer [] as well, regardless of how strange it looks.

With the advent of these : codes the classic \w, etc., remain strictly in the C locale. Thus your choice of patterns determines if grep uses the current locale or not.

[A-Z] should follow locale, but you may need to set LC_ALL rather than LANG, especially if the system sets LC_ALL to a different value for your.

Comment: So you say [A-Z] remains strictly in C locale? But my whole question was about it not being in C locale.

Comment: Try setting the LC_ALL environment variable rather than LANG.

Comment: LC_ALL is probably a better variable to use than LANG as it's the one the grep checks for first. But currently it doesn't make any difference for me.

Comment: Using the date command is a quick way to test if locales are enabled: LC_ALL=et_EE date