# How to convert a vector of strings to Title Case

Tags: regex, r, replace

I have a vector of strings in lower case. I'd like to change them to title case, meaning the first letter of every word would be capitalized. I've managed to do it with a double loop, but I'm hoping there's a more efficient and elegant way to do it, perhaps a one-liner with `gsub` and a regex.

Here's some sample data, along with the double loop that works, followed by other things I tried that didn't work.

```
strings = c("first phrase", "another phrase to convert",
            "and here's another one", "last-one")

# For each string in the strings vector, find the position of each 
#  instance of a space followed by a letter
matches = gregexpr("\\b[a-z]+", strings) 

# For each string in the strings vector, convert the first letter 
#  of each word to upper case
for (i in 1:length(strings)) {

  # Extract the position of each regex match for the string in row i
  #  of the strings vector.
  match.positions = matches[[i]][1:length(matches[[i]])] 

  # Convert the letter in each match position to upper case
  for (j in 1:length(match.positions)) {

    substr(strings[i], match.positions[j], match.positions[j]) = 
      toupper(substr(strings[i], match.positions[j], match.positions[j]))
  }
}
```

This worked, but it seems inordinately complicated. I resorted to it only after experimenting unsuccessfully with more straightforward approaches. Here are some of the things I tried, along with the output:

```
# Google search suggested \\U might work, but evidently not in R
gsub("(\\b[a-z]+)", "\\U\\1" ,strings)
[1] "Ufirst Uphrase"                "Uanother Uphrase Uto Uconvert"
[3] "Uand Uhere'Us Uanother Uone"   "Ulast-Uone"                   

# I tried this on a lark, but to no avail
gsub("(\\b[a-z]+)", toupper("\\1"), strings)
[1] "first phrase"              "another phrase to convert"
[3] "and here's another one"    "last-one"
```

The regex captures the correct positions in each string as shown by a call to `gregexpr`, but the replacement string is clearly not working as desired.

If you can't already tell, I'm relatively new to regexes and would appreciate help on how to get the replacement to work correctly. I'd also like to learn how to structure the regex so as to avoid capturing a letter after an apostrophe, since I don't want to change the case of those letters.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The main problem is that you're missing `perl=TRUE` (and your regex is slightly wrong, although that may be a result of flailing around to try to fix the first problem).

Using `[:lower:]` instead of `[a-z]` (or `[:alpha:]` instead of `[A-Za-z]`) is slightly safer in case your code ends up being run in some weird ([sorry, Estonians](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6799872/how-to-make-grep-a-z-independent-of-locale)) locale where `z` is not the last letter of the alphabet ...

```
re_from <- "\\b([[:alpha:]])([[:alpha:]]+)"
strings <- c("first phrase", "another phrase to convert",
             "and here's another one", "last-one")
gsub(re_from, "\\U\\1\\L\\2" ,strings, perl=TRUE)
## [1] "First Phrase"              "Another Phrase To Convert"
## [3] "And Here's Another One"    "Last-One"
```

You may prefer to use `\\E` (stop capitalization) rather than `\\L` (start lowercase), depending on what rules you want to follow, e.g.:

```
string2 <- "using AIC for model selection"
gsub(re_from, "\\U\\1\\E\\2" ,string2, perl=TRUE)
## [1] "Using AIC For Model Selection"
```

Comment: Hi @BenBolker, your re_from should be `"\\b([[:alpha:]])([[:alpha:]]+)"` instead of `"\\b([[:lower:]])([[:lower:]]+)"`. Otherwise, there's no point in using `\\E` in your last remark.

Answer (score 8):

Without using `regex`, the help page for `tolower` has two example functions that will do this.

The more robust version is

```
capwords <- function(s, strict = FALSE) {
    cap <- function(s) paste(toupper(substring(s, 1, 1)),
                  {s <- substring(s, 2); if(strict) tolower(s) else s},
                             sep = "", collapse = " " )
    sapply(strsplit(s, split = " "), cap, USE.NAMES = !is.null(names(s)))
}
capwords(c("using AIC for model selection"))
## ->  [1] "Using AIC For Model Selection"
```

To get your `regex` approach (almost) working you need to set `perl = TRUE)

```
gsub("(\\b[a-z]{1})", "\\U\\1" ,strings, perl=TRUE)


[1] "First Phrase"              "Another Phrase To Convert"
[3] "And Here'S Another One"    "Last-One"
```

but you will need to deal with apostrophes slightly better perhaps

```
sapply(lapply(strsplit(strings, ' '), gsub, pattern = '^([[:alnum:]]{1})', replace = '\\U\\1', perl = TRUE), paste,collapse = ' ')
```

A quick search of SO found https://stackoverflow.com/a/6365349/1385941

Comment: Sadly, my no-so-quick search of SO didn't turn up the question you mention. I tried "Convert string to title case", "convert first letter of each word to upper case", "capitalize first letter of each word", etc. but somehow didn't hit on the magic search string. In any case, I'm glad to have the answers to my questions, since they add a few more options and some additional insight into how regexes work.

Answer (score 6):

Already excellent answers here.  Here's one using a convenience function from the reports package:

```
strings <- c("first phrase", "another phrase to convert",
    "and here's another one", "last-one")

CA(strings)

## > CA(strings)
## [1] "First Phrase"              "Another Phrase To Convert"
## [3] "And Here's Another One"    "Last-one"
```

Though it doesn't capitalize one as it didn't make sense to do so for my purposes.

**Update** I manage the **qdapRegex** package that has the `TC` (title case) function that does true title case:

```
TC(strings)

## [[1]]
## [1] "First Phrase"
## 
## [[2]]
## [1] "Another Phrase to Convert"
## 
## [[3]]
## [1] "And Here's Another One"
## 
## [[4]]
## [1] "Last-One"
```

Answer (score 4):

I'll throw one more into the mix for fun:

```
topropper(strings)
[1] "First Phrase"              "Another Phrase To Convert" "And Here's Another One"   
[4] "Last-one"  

topropper <- function(x) {
  # Makes Proper Capitalization out of a string or collection of strings. 
  sapply(x, function(strn)
   { s <- strsplit(strn, "\\s")[[1]]
       paste0(toupper(substring(s, 1,1)), 
             tolower(substring(s, 2)),
             collapse=" ")}, USE.NAMES=FALSE)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is another one-liner, based on `stringr` package:

```
str_to_title(strings, locale = "en")
```

where `strings` is your vector of strings.

[Source](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/reference/case.html)

Answer (score 0):

The best way for conversion of any case to any other case is the use of `snakecase` package in r.

Simply use the package

```
library(snakecase)
strings = c("first phrase", "another phrase to convert",
        "and here's another one", "last-one")

to_title_case(strings)

## [1] "First Phrase"              "Another Phrase to Convert" 
## [3] "And Here s Another One"    "Last One"
```

Keep Coding!