# First letter to upper case

Tags: r, string

Is there a other version to make the first letter of each string capital and also with FALSE for flac perl?

```
name<-"hallo"
gsub("(^[[:alpha:]])", "\\U\\1", name, perl=TRUE)
```

Comment: Is it always just one word? This might help - [How to convert a vector of strings to Title Case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15776732/how-to-convert-a-vector-of-strings-to-title-case). See answer by @mnel

Comment: The examples in `toupper` might be useful, e.g. `.simpleCap`

Comment: @Henrik that capitalizes every word.

Comment: @zx8754 I cant see a solution with perl flac FALSE

Comment: @SimonO101, perhaps I misunderstood what Klaus ment by "each string".

Answer (score 116):

You can try something like:

```
name<-"hallo"
paste(toupper(substr(name, 1, 1)), substr(name, 2, nchar(name)), sep="")
```

Or another way is to have a function like:

```
firstup <- function(x) {
  substr(x, 1, 1) <- toupper(substr(x, 1, 1))
  x
}
```

Examples:

```
firstup("abcd")
## [1] Abcd

firstup(c("hello", "world"))
## [1] "Hello" "World"
```

Comment: This I also watched out but it looks not so flexible if something will change later

Comment: @Klaus but it *exactly* answers the question you posted. It is *really* bad form to change the parameters of the question *after* someone has posted a working answer. Not cool/fair! Ask a new question.

Comment: Also sometimes it will be necessary to have all other chars except first in lower case. So, adding "x <- tolower(x)" will be useful

Answer (score 80):

As pointed out in the comment, it is now possible to do:

`stringr::str_to_title("iwejofwe asdFf FFFF")`

`stringr` uses `stringi` under the hood which takes care of complex internationalization, unicode, etc., you can do:
`stri_trans_totitle("kaCk, DSJAIDO, Sasdd.", opts_brkiter = stri_opts_brkiter(type = "sentence"))`

There is a C or C++ library underneath `stringi`.

Comment: Now there is a stringr wrapper: `str_to_title`

Comment: This does not answer the question, as `str_to_title` converts **every letter in the string to lowercase, except the first letter of each word**. E.g., `str_to_title("AB ABC abc")` returns `Ab Abc Abc`. So, among other things, it destroys acronyms.

Answer (score 36):

In `stringr`, there's `str_to_sentence()` which does something similar. Not quite an answer to this question, but it solves the problem I had.

```r
str_to_sentence(c("not today judas", "i love cats", "other Caps converteD to lower though"))
#> [1] "Not today judas"  "I love cats"  "Other caps converted to lower though"
```

Comment: Can't understand why this was downvoted. Exactly what I was looking for. Upvoted it.

Comment: Problem with str_to_sentence is that it will turn eg: EFFG-1 to Effg-1 while str_replace(input, "^\\w{1}", toupper) keeps the original structure if multiple letters are uppercase. For eg gene names this is a better solution.

Answer (score 19):

for the lazy typer:

```
  paste0(toupper(substr(name, 1, 1)), substr(name, 2, nchar(name)))
```

will do too.

Comment: If by “super lazy” you mean “knows that `paste0(x)` exists and is equivalent to `paste(x, sep = '')`”.

Comment: @KonradRudolph you are 100% right -> With lazy i mean just less code to type and maintain. (can make quite a difference if you start concatenating code into one Functional Programming line - like I do a lot - ) :^)

Comment: And paste0 is faster.

Comment: This answers the question and uses base R. Should be the accepted answer IMO.

Answer (score 10):

I like the "tidyverse" way using stringr with a oneliner

```
library(stringr)
input <- c("this", "is", "a", "test")
str_replace(input, "^\\w{1}", toupper)
```

Resulting in:

```
[1] "This" "Is"   "A"    "Test"
```

Answer (score 8):

Often we want **only** the first letter upper case, rest of the string lower case. In such scenario, we need to convert the whole string to lower case first.

Inspired by @alko989 answer, the function will be:

```
firstup <- function(x) {
  x <- tolower(x)
  substr(x, 1, 1) <- toupper(substr(x, 1, 1))
  x
}
```

Examples:

```
firstup("ABCD")
## [1] Abcd
```

Another option is to use `str_to_title` in `stringr` package

```
dog <- "The quick brown dog"    
str_to_title(dog)
## [1] "The Quick Brown Dog"
```

Answer (score 3):

I was also looking for the answer on this, but the replies did not consider the case of strings starting with numbers or symbols. Also, the question was: "make the first letter of each string capital", not every word.

```
v = c("123.1 test test", "test", "test test", ". test")
stringr::str_replace(v, "([[:alpha:]])", toupper)
## [1] "123.1 Test test" "Test"            "Test test"       ". Test"
```