# Positive lookbehind on non-ASCII characters in R

Tags: r, regex

I have an R function which tries to capitalise the first letter of every "word"

```
proper = function(x){
  gsub("(?<=\\b)([[:alpha:]])", "\\U\\1", x, perl = TRUE)
}
```

This works pretty well, but when I have a word with a Māori macron in it like `Māori` I get improper capitalisation, e.g.

```
> proper("Māori")
[1] "MāOri"
```

Clearly the RE engine thinks the macron `ā` is a word boundary. Not sure why.

Comment: Does **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18509527/first-letter-to-upper-case)** post help? `str_to_title` from `stringr` doesn't capitalize the o in Māori either.

Comment: Is there a unicode flag (like the one used in https://regex101.com/r/unVXlI/1)?  BTW, for something like a word boundary, it may not be necessary to use a lookbehind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using a PCRE regex engine (enabled with `perl=TRUE`) you must pass the `(*UCP)` flag to the regex so that all shorthands and word boundaries could detect correct symbols/locations inside Unicode text:

```
proper = function(x){
  gsub("(*UCP)\\b([[:alpha:]])", "\\U\\1", x, perl = TRUE)
}
proper("Māori")
## [1] "Māori"
```

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/SZ9Onj).

Note that `\b` is already a zero-width assertion and does not have to be placed into a positive lookbehind, i.e. `(?<=\b)` = `\b`.

Comment: Also, `"(*UCP)\\b([[:alpha:]])"` can be replaced with a shorter `"(*UCP)\\b(\\p{L})"`

Comment: Excellent. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`\b` basically denotes a boundary on characters other than `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` which includes multibyte characters as well unless a modifier called `Unicode` is set to affect engine behavior.

Unfortunately, `gsub` in R doesn't have this flag or I couldn't find anything about it in documentations.

A workaround would be:

```
(?<!\\S)([[:alpha:]])
```

which, in other hand, obviously fails on `āmori`.