# R lang: First letter to upper case

Tags: r, data-conversion

I'm trying to convert all data in the column to "First letter to upper case"
The following code replaces all data with the first row,

```
simpleCap <- function(x) {
  s <- strsplit(x, " ")[[1]]
  paste(toupper(substring(s, 1,1)), substring(s, 2),
        sep="", collapse=" ")
}
allDestination$Categories <- simpleCap(allDestination$Categories)
```

Sample data

```
japan/okinawa/okinawa-other-islands
japan/hokkaido/hokkaido-north/furano-biei-tomamu
japan/hokkaido/hokkaido-north/asahikawa-sounkyo
japan/hokkaido/hokkaido-north/wakkanai-rishiri-rebun
japan/hokkaido/hokkaido-east/kushiro-akan-nemuro
```

The function code sample comes from
[First letter to upper case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18509527/first-letter-to-upper-case)

How to make the function as "column compatible" instead of only replacing only a single value?

Comment: Your function explicitly works on the first element by using `[[1]]`. Instead, keep `s` as a `list`, and operate over all of it with `sapply`.

Comment: What results do you expect from the sample above?

Comment: You could use the `capitalize` function from the `Hmisc` package

Comment: You can `vectorize` your function. The simple way can be as `simpleCapV <- Vectorize(simpleCap)` . Now use `simpleCapV(allDestination$Categories)`.

Comment: @Onyambu, I get repeated result of the first row

Comment: @r2evans, so I just remove the `[[1]]` right?

Comment: What do you mean by repeated results of the first row?. Can you post the results you need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a negative look behind, to capitalize every letter which is preceded by a non letter or is at the beginning of the sentence ie `(?:^|(?<=\\W))(.)` or also you can think of it as to capitalize a letter which is not preceded by a letter ie `(?<!\\w)(.)`

```
gsub("(?<!\\w)(.)","\\U\\1",dat1$V1,perl = TRUE) 

[1] "Japan/Okinawa/Okinawa-Other-Islands"                 
[2] "Japan/Hokkaido/Hokkaido-North/Furano-Biei-Tomamu"    
[3] "Japan/Hokkaido/Hokkaido-North/Asahikawa-Sounkyo"     
[4] "Japan/Hokkaido/Hokkaido-North/Wakkanai-Rishiri-Rebun"
[5] "Japan/Hokkaido/Hokkaido-East/Kushiro-Akan-Nemuro"
```

data:

```
 dat1=read.table(strip=T,text="japan/okinawa/okinawa-other-islands
       japan/hokkaido/hokkaido-north/furano-biei-tomamu
       japan/hokkaido/hokkaido-north/asahikawa-sounkyo
       japan/hokkaido/hokkaido-north/wakkanai-rishiri-rebun
       japan/hokkaido/hokkaido-east/kushiro-akan-nemuro")
```

Comment: using `gsub("(?<!\\w)(.)","\\U\\1", tolower(dat1$V1), perl = TRUE)` would be robust to entries like `JAPAN/HOKKAIDO/HOKKAIDO/NORTH/FURANO/BIEI/ROMARU`.

Answer (score 6):

Tidyverse Answer - There is a function specifically for this **stringr::str_to_title**

```
library(tidyverse)
```

data example:

```
data_1 <- 
  data.frame("japan/okinawa/okinawa-other-islands",
             "japan/hokkaido/hokkaido-north/furano-biei-tomamu",
             "japan/hokkaido/hokkaido-north/asahikawa-sounkyo",
             "japan/hokkaido/hokkaido-north/wakkanai-rishiri-rebun",
             "japan/hokkaido/hokkaido-east/kushiro-akan-nemuro",
             stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

function at work:

```
> str_to_title(data_1)

[1] "Japan/Okinawa/Okinawa-Other-Islands"                 
[2] "Japan/Hokkaido/Hokkaido-North/Furano-Biei-Tomamu"    
[3] "Japan/Hokkaido/Hokkaido-North/Asahikawa-Sounkyo"     
[4] "Japan/Hokkaido/Hokkaido-North/Wakkanai-Rishiri-Rebun"
[5] "Japan/Hokkaido/Hokkaido-East/Kushiro-Akan-Nemuro"
```

https://stringr.tidyverse.org/reference/case.html