# ft_tokenizer tokenizes words to lower, I want it to be as they are

Tags: r, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, sparkr, sparklyr

I am using ft_tokenizer for spark dataframe in R.
and it tokenizes each word and changes it to all lower, I want the words to be in the format they originally are.

```
text_data <- data_frame(
  x = c("This IS a sentence", "So is this")
)

tokenized <- text_data_tbl %>%
  ft_tokenizer("x", "word")


tokenized$word
## [[1]]
## [[1]][[1]]
## [1] "this"
## 
## [[1]][[2]]
## [1] "is"
##
## [[1]][[3]]
## [1] "a"
```

I want:

```
tokenized$word
## [[1]]
## [[1]][[1]]
## [1] "This"
## 
## [[1]][[2]]
## [1] "IS"
##
## [[1]][[3]]
## [1] "a"
```

Comment: Why do you think capitalization is important? I am just curious what your idea for nlp.

Comment: I want to use the tokenized words to match it with a list of keyword, for which I need exact matches. i,e, in the list of keywords, if I have "This", I want an exact match to it, which is not possible right now because tokenizing changes "This" to "this".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [First letter to upper case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18509527/first-letter-to-upper-case)

Comment: take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18509527/first-letter-to-upper-case/18509816

Comment: No, I don't want to change each first letter to upper case. I just want it to tokenize the word as it is. I will edit my query to be more precise.

Comment: Simple is best. If you want to split to list format and then mapping some keywords, you don't need to use the `ft_tokenizer`.

Comment: Are `text_data` and `text_data_tbl` supposed to be the same thing?

Comment: yes, but I found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is not possible with `ft_tokenizer`. From `?ft_tokenizer`

> A tokenizer that converts the input string to lowercase and then splits it by white spaces.

So it's basic feature is to convert the string to lowercase and split on white-space which I guess cannot be changed. Consider doing

```
text_data$new_x <- lapply(strsplit(text_data$x, "\\s+"), as.list)
```

which will give the same output as expected and you can continue your process as it is from here.

```
text_data$new_x
#[[1]]
#[[1]][[1]]
#[1] "This"

#[[1]][[2]]
#[1] "IS"

#[[1]][[3]]
#[1] "a"

#[[1]][[4]]
#[1] "sentence"


#[[2]]
#[[2]][[1]]
#[1] "So"

#[[2]][[2]]
#[1] "is"

#[[2]][[3]]
#[1] "this"
```

Comment: is it possible to apply the same function on spark data frame? since text_data is a spark data frame.

Comment: @VasudhaJain Should be possible but I am not exactly sure how as I do not have a spark dataframe to test this. Is it possible for you to apply this on a dataframe instead using `df <- collect(text_data)` or `df <- as.data.frame(text_data)` ?

Comment: my main aim is to make this work on spark dataframe. Even if it works on regular r dataframe, it won't be of any help to me.

Comment: @VasudhaJain I see. I was thinking if you could do this part in regular dataframe, then convert it back to spark dataframe and continue from there. Maybe somebody else might know.

Comment: if I do that in regular dataframe, a list will be created. and it's again a challenge to convert the list into spark df.