# `stringr` to convert first letter only to uppercase in dataframe

Tags: r, string, stringr, uppercase

I would like to capitalize the first letter of each word in a column, without converting remaining letters to lowercase. I am trying to use `stringr` since its vectorized and plays well with dataframes, but would also use another solution. Below is a reprex showing my desired output and various attempts. I am able to select the first letter only, but then not sure how to capitalize it. Thank you for your help!

I also reviewed related posts, but wasn't sure how to apply those solutions in my case (i.e., within a dataframe):

[First letter to upper case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18509527/first-letter-to-upper-case/18509816)

[Capitalize the first letter of both words in a two word string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364783/capitalize-the-first-letter-of-both-words-in-a-two-word-string)

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

words <-
  tribble(
    ~word, ~number,
    "problems", 99,
    "Answer", 42,
    "golden ratio", 1.61,
    "NOTHING", 0
  )

# Desired output
new_words <-
  tribble(
    ~word, ~number,
    "Problems", 99,
    "Answer", 42,
    "Golden Ratio", 1.61,
    "NOTHING", 0
  )

# Converts first letter of each word to upper and all other to lower
mutate(words, word = str_to_title(word))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>   word         number
#>   <chr>         <dbl>
#> 1 Problems      99   
#> 2 Answer        42   
#> 3 Golden Ratio   1.61
#> 4 Nothing        0

# Some attempts
mutate(words, word = str_replace_all(word, "(?<=^|\\s)([a-zA-Z])", "X"))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>   word         number
#>   <chr>         <dbl>
#> 1 Xroblems      99   
#> 2 Xnswer        42   
#> 3 Xolden Xatio   1.61
#> 4 XOTHING        0
mutate(words, word = str_replace_all(word, "(?<=^|\\s)([a-zA-Z])", "\\1"))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>   word         number
#>   <chr>         <dbl>
#> 1 problems      99   
#> 2 Answer        42   
#> 3 golden ratio   1.61
#> 4 NOTHING        0
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a base R solution using `gsub`:

```r
words$word <- gsub("\\b([a-z])", "\\U\\1", words$word, perl=TRUE)
```

This will replace the first lowercase letter of every word with its uppercase version.  Note that the `\b` word boundary will match a lowercase preceded by either whitespace or the start of the column's value.

Comment: Thank you, I figured out how to integrate your solution into my pipe: `mutate(words, word = gsub("\\b([a-z])", "\\U\\1", word, perl=TRUE))`

Answer (score 3):

We could use `str_to_title` function from `stringr` package.

The problem is that `NOTHING` turns to `Nothing`.

But we can overcome this with an `ifelse` -> checking if first character is uppercase then leaf else make uppercase.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
words %>% 
    mutate(word = ifelse(str_detect(word, "^[:upper:]+$"), word,str_to_title(word)))
```

Output:

```
  word         number
  <chr>         <dbl>
1 Problems      99   
2 Answer        42   
3 Golden Ratio   1.61
4 NOTHING        0
```

Comment: Great idea, thank you! However, that will still miss words like "nOTHING" - however, the suggestion to wrap in an ifelse is good to keep in mind.

Answer (score 1):

According to https://community.rstudio.com/t/is-there-will-there-be-perl-support-in-stringr/38016/3 stringr uses stringi and the ICU engine, so it does not and will not support perl type regex (which is what enables the \U\1 part in other answers). So you should use the gsub with perl=TRUE answer by @Tim.