# Proper capitalization of name strings mixed in with company names

Tags: regex, r

I've got a list of owner names in all caps that I'd like to convert to proper capitalization:

```
                   owner1
 1:    DXXXXX JOSEPH V JR
 2:          MIRNA NXXXXX
 3:          ADRIAN TXXXX
 4: CUTLER PXXXXXXXXX LLC
 5:    GVM PXXXXXXXXX LLC
 6:      EARLENA RXXXXXXX
 7:      NATHANIEL TXXXXX
 8:         DXXXXXX DONNA
 9:     LXXXX ELAINE E TR
10:      SXXXXXX KIMBERLY
```

(for reproduction purposes:

```
 owner1<-c("DXXXXX JOSEPH V JR","MIRNA NXXXXX","ADRIAN TXXXX",
           "CUTLER PXXXXXXXXX LLC","GVM PXXXXXXXXX LLC",
           "EARLENA RXXXXXXX","NATHANIEL TXXXXX","DXXXXXX DONNA",
           "LXXXX ELAINE E TR","SXXXXXX KIMBERLY")
```

)

Desired output:

```
                   owner1
 1:   Dxxxxx Joseph V. Jr
 2:          Mirna Nxxxxx
 3:          Adrian Txxxx
 4: Cutler Pxxxxxxxxx LLC
 5:    GVM Pxxxxxxxxx LLC
 6:      Earlena Rxxxxxxx
 7:      Nathaniel Txxxxx
 8:         Dxxxxxx Donna
 9:    Lxxxx Elaine E. TR
10:      Sxxxxxx Kimberly
```

A big first step is a version of the `.simpleCap` function mentioned in `?chartr`:

```
.simpleCap <- function(x) {
    s <- strsplit(tolower(x), " ")[[1]]
    paste(toupper(substring(s, 1, 1)), substring(s, 2),
          sep = "", collapse = " ")
}
```

This is a large chunk of the problem, but fails on 4, 5 and 9. I can supplement this to treat key phrases (LLC, TR, etc.) separately, but this still leaves something like observation 5.

Here's the function I've got so far (sped up wonderfully by @eipi10's solution below, which vectorized the `.simpleCap` function, allowing the whole function to be applied to vectors):

```
to.proper<-function(strings){
  #vectorized version of .simpleCap;
  #  I've also built in that I know `strings` is all caps
  res<-gsub("\\b([A-Z])([A-Z]+)*","\\U\\1\\L\\2",strings,perl=T)
  #In my data, some Irish/Scottish names separated the MC prefix
  #  Also, re-capitalize following a hyphen
  res<-gsub("\\bMc\\s","Mc",gsub("(-.)","\\U\\1",res,perl=T))
  for (init in c("[A-Z]","Inc","Assoc","Co",
                 "Jr","Sr","Tr","Bros")){
    #Add a period after common abbreviations
    res<-gsub(paste0("\\b(",init,")\\b"),"\\1.",res)
  }
  for (abbr in c("[B-DF-HJ-NP-TV-XZ][b-df-hj-np-tv-xz]{2,}",
                 "Pa","Ii","Iii","Iv","Lp","Tj",
                 "Xiv","Ll","Yml","Us")){
    #Re-capitalize any string of >=3 consonants (excluding
    #   Y for such names as LYNN and WYNN), as well as
    #   some other common phrases that need upper-casing
    res<-gsub(paste0("\\b(",abbr,")\\b"),"\\U\\1",res,perl=T)
  }
  #Re-capitalize post-Mc letters, e.g. in Mcmahon
  gsub("\\bMc([a-z])","Mc\\U\\1",res,perl=T)
}
```

Any ideas for robust-ish ways to leave potentially unpredicted abbreviations alone in this process (particularly, like those in observation 5 which are uncommon)?

Comment: I think you may need some list of suffixes to leave `LLC, TR` out of the match and not to be used in the capitalization

Comment: In addition to @akrun's suggestion, have you tried stri_trans_totitle() from the stringi package?

Comment: @lawyeR That should also give the same problem.  I tried it :-)

Comment: @lawyeR is that in the development version of `stringi`? I'm not seeing it in the [documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringi/stringi.pdf)

Comment: Yes, look in the pdf documentation on page 132

Comment: See edit for current working function; the real trouble is the uncommon abbreviations like that in observation 5. Perhaps just check if there's three consonants in a row??

Comment: @lawyeR could you link the documentation you're seeing? The link I posted is only 117 pages :o

Comment: Easily reproducible data would be nice. I guess in a regex question, perhaps the expectation is that folks know how to ingest that, though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a function using a Regex to convert strings to title case (adapted from [@BenBolker's answer to a question I asked on SO a while back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15776732/how-to-convert-a-vector-of-strings-to-title-case)).

The function is written so that you can pass an argument called `exceptions` that deals with special cases like `GVM`. I'm not sure if this is flexible enough for your needs, since you have to hard-code the exceptions, but I thought I'd post it and see if anyone can suggest improvements.

```
dat = data.frame(owner1 = c("DXXXXX JOSEPH V JR","MIRNA NXXXXX","ADRIAN TXXXX",
                                    "CUTLER PXXXXXXXXX LLC","GVM PXXXXXXXXX LLC",
                                    "EARLENA RXXXXXXX","NATHANIEL TXXXXX","DXXXXXX DONNA",
                                    "LXXXX ELAINE E TR","SXXXXXX KIMBERLY"))

# Convert a string to title case
tc = function(strings, exceptions="\\b(gvm)\\b") {

  # Convert to title case, excluding terminal LLC, TR, etc.
  title.case = gsub("\\b([a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z]+)*( LLC| TR| FBO| LP)?", 
                    "\\U\\1\\L\\2\\U\\3", strings, perl=TRUE)

  # Add a period after initials (presumed to be any lone capital letter)
  title.case = gsub(" ([A-Z]) ", " \\1\\. ", title.case)

  # Deal with exceptions
  title.case = gsub(exceptions, "\\U\\1", title.case, perl=TRUE, ignore.case=TRUE)

  return(title.case)
}

dat$title.case = tc(dat$owner1)

                  owner1            title.case
1     DXXXXX JOSEPH V JR   Dxxxxx Joseph V. Jr
2           MIRNA NXXXXX          Mirna Nxxxxx
3           ADRIAN TXXXX          Adrian Txxxx
4  CUTLER PXXXXXXXXX LLC Cutler Pxxxxxxxxx LLC
5     GVM PXXXXXXXXX LLC    GVM Pxxxxxxxxx LLC
6       EARLENA RXXXXXXX      Earlena Rxxxxxxx
7       NATHANIEL TXXXXX      Nathaniel Txxxxx
8          DXXXXXX DONNA         Dxxxxxx Donna
9      LXXXX ELAINE E TR    Lxxxx Elaine E. TR
10      SXXXXXX KIMBERLY      Sxxxxxx Kimberly
```

Comment: Big props for a vectorized version of the `.simpleCap` function I was using, this sped up my code substantially. I'm eventually settled in on a function close to the one you presented. Mine is more tailor-made; to generalize it, I would probably pass `exceptions` and `initialize` arguments as well.

Comment: I also am using the following to figure out what sort of 2-letter consonant phrases are sitting around & going case-by-case on them: `regmatches(string,regexpr("\\b[B-DF-HJ-NP-TV-XZ]{2}\\b",string))` (unfortunately a blanket exception is inappropriate due the abundance of abbreviations like Jr, Sr, Co, Sc (School), Ch (Church) and some Vietnamese names like Ng, etc.)