# Remove white spaces between letters [A-Za-z]

Tags: r, regex

How to remove whitespaces between letters NOT numbers

For example:

Input

```
I ES P 010 000 000 000 000 000 001 001 000 000 IESP 000 000
```

Output

```
IESP 010 000 000 000 000 000 001 001 000 000 IESP 000 000
```

I tried something like this

```
gsub("(?<=\\b\\w)\\s(?=\\w\\b)", "", x,perl=T)
```

But wasn't able to arrive at the output I was hoping for

Comment: [`([^\n\S]*)([A-Z])([^\n\S]*)`](https://regex101.com/r/ocX3cW/2)

Comment: @Gurman - What's the point posting answer as a comment?

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis I was just giving an alternative. An answer was already posted by some other person which I thought was correct. It shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use

```
Input <- "I ES P E ES P 010 000 000 000 000 000 001 001 000 000 IESP 000 000"
gsub("(?<=[A-Z])\\s+(?=[A-Z])", "", Input, perl=TRUE, ignore.case = TRUE)
## gsub("(*UCP)(?<=\\p{L})\\s+(?=\\p{L})", "", Input, perl=TRUE) ## for Unicode
```

See the [R demo online](https://ideone.com/xvLbbh) and a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pGqjwQ/1).

*NOTE*: The `ignore.case = TRUE` will make the pattern case insensitive, if it is not expected, remove this argument.

**Details**

- `(?<=[A-Z])` (or `(?<=\p{L})`) - a letter must appear immediately to the left of the current location (without adding it to the match)
- `\\s+` - 1 or more whitespaces
- `(?=[A-Z])` (or `(?=\\p{L})`) - a letter must appear immediately to the right of the current location (without adding it to the match).

Comment: This should be the accepted answer (+1) @jonnyblue8

Comment: Wiktor Appreciate the detailed explanation. 
PoGibas Thanks for the help & quick reply

Answer (score 6):

Use `gsub` to replace whitespace `" "` with nothing `""` between letters then return replacement and letters.

```
Input <- "I ES P 010 000 000 000 000 000 001 001 000 000 IESP 000 000"
gsub("([A-Z]) ([A-Z])", "\\1\\2", Input)
[1] "IESP 010 000 000 000 000 000 001 001 000 000 IESP 000 000"
```

Edit after [**@Wiktor Stribiżew**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%C5%BCew) comment (replaced `[A-z]` to `[a-zA-Z]`):

For lower and upper case use `[a-zA-Z]`

```
Input <- "I ES P 010 000 000 000 000 000 001 001 000 000 IESP 000 000 aaa ZZZ"
gsub("([a-zA-Z]) ([a-zA-Z])", "\\1\\2", Input)
[1] "IESP 010 000 000 000 000 000 001 001 000 000 IESP 000 000 aaaZZZ"
```

Comment: [Do not use `[A-z]` to only match letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29771901/why-is-this-regex-allowing-a-caret/29771926#29771926). It matches more than just letters. Besides, the `gsub("([A-Z]) ([A-Z])", "\\1\\2", Input)` won't work for `I E P 1000` input.

Comment: See my answer for overlapping cases.

Comment: probably even better to use `[[:alpha:]]` rather than `[A-Za-z]` in case you happen to be in [an Estonian locale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6799872/how-to-make-grep-a-z-independent-of-locale) ...