# what's the difference between grep [a-z] and grep '[a-z]'?

Tags: grep

Recently I found that using grep with/without quotes return different results.

```
grep [a-z] test
```

return

> insert something

while

```
grep '[a-z]' test
```

return

> Hello
>
> insert something
>
> good bye
>
> #!/binbash

So I got confused what's the difference between these two usage?

the PATTERN **MUST** to be quoted?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make grep \[A-Z\] independent of locale?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6799872/how-to-make-grep-a-z-independent-of-locale)

Comment: Nope, the LC_ALL=C didn't fix my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shell interprets `[a-z]` first if it is not quoted, before ever passing it to `grep`.

`[a-z]` is expanded to all the **filenames** found in the working directory that consist of exactly one letter between **a** and **z**.

I'll bet if you do a **`ls`** you will find a file (in the current directory) with the name `t`, or some other letter that is only present in "insert something" but not in the other strings (lines of text). If in your working directory you have several files, but exactly one has a one-letter name like **`t`**, then your first command is expanded to `grep t test`.

So - yes, you must quote your regular expression, so it is passed as is to `grep` and it is not processed by the shell.

Comment: yes. As you said I found a 't' named file in the dir.

Comment: @admin - hehe, that was a guess; it could have been **`m`** too (another letter that is present in that line but not in the other three).